# Sql Server - user CTE in subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression

This question has been asked before -

[How we can use CTE in subquery in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914151/how-we-can-use-cte-in-subquery-in-sql-server)

The only answer suggested was "Just define your CTE on top and access it in the subquery?"

This works, but I would really like to be able to use a CTE in the following scenarios -

1. as a subquery in a SELECT
2. as a derived table in the FROM clause of a SELECT

Both of these work in PostgreSQL. With Sql Server 2005, I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'".

The reason I would like it is that most of my queries are constructed dynamically, and I would like to be able to define a CTE, save it somewhere, and then drop it in to a more complex query on demand.

If Sql Server simply does not support this usage, I will have to accept it, but I have not read anything that states that it is not allowed.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, CTE's must be at the top of the query.  If you construct queries dynamically, you could store a list of CTE's in addition to the query.  Before you send the query to SQL server, you can prefix the query with a list of CTE's:

```
; with Cte1 as (...definition 1...),
  Cte2 as (...definition 2...),
  Cte3 as (...definition 3...),
  ...
...constructed query...
```

This is assuming that you're constructing the SQL outside of SQL Server.

You could also consider creating views.  Views can contain CTE's, and they can be used as a subquery or derived table.  Views are a good choice if you generate SQL infrequently, say only during an installation or as part of a deployment.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support this much-required feature.  I too have been looking for help on this.
MS SQL Server does not support Temporary Views either as opposed to PostgreSQL.  The above-mentioned solution is also likely to work only if all the CTE definitions could be generated before-hand and do not have conflicting names in each of the sub-queries either - the purpose being that these CTE definitions may be different for each level of a sub-query.

Sad but true !!!

Regards,
Kapil