# No column name was specified for column 2 of 't' T_SQL error

Tags: sql

PLease i want to return only debtorid from this T-SQL . It gives the error "
No column name was specified for column 2 of 't'." My query is below.

```
 with t as 
(SELECT debtorid,MAX(dbo.FollowUp.followupdate) FROM dbo.FollowUp WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE
( dbo.FollowUp.FollowUpDate >= '01-01-2011 00:00:00:000' and dbo.FollowUp.FollowUpDate <= '01-13-2014 23:59:59.000'
and Status = 'PTP')  GROUP BY [Status], DebtorId)

SELECT t.debtorid FROM t;
```

WIth my little knowledge , i thought the above should work fine for me. however, it didn't.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you computing an aggregate if you're just going to ignore it? Do you explicitly want to ignore anything with a follow up date of, say, `2014-01-13T23:59:59.443`, or have you just not considered that using `<` and a value of `2014-01-14T00:00:00` would be cleaner (especially since that can be shortened to `20140114`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Common Table Expressions or CTE, in CTE you must have column name as per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). You can also refer for CTE best practices:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/10/sql-server-common-table-expression-cte-and-few-observation/

```
;with t as 
(
    SELECT FWP.debtorid
        ,MAX(FWP.followupdate) followupdate 
    FROM dbo.FollowUp  FWP WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE
    ( 
        FWP.FollowUpDate >= '01-01-2011 00:00:00:000' 
         and FWP.FollowUpDate <= '01-13-2014 23:59:59.000'
         and FWP.Status = 'PTP'
    )  GROUP BY FWP.[Status], FWP.DebtorId
)
SELECT t.debtorid FROM t;
```

Comment: Sorry Pranav. Please how do i use this as a subquery? I tried but its given me error. When i run the query independently it works. However, cant incorporate in another query.

Comment: I think this will help :http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e269e7e-6411-4134-a181-63c1280b4c7e/how-to-use-sql-hints-within-ctesubquery  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107865/sql-server-user-cte-in-subquery http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml

Comment: This will not work straight forward CTE will be above & you can use union in below with CTE alias

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a name to your second column, e.g.:

```
with t as 
(SELECT debtorid, MAX(dbo.FollowUp.followupdate) maxFollowup 
 FROM dbo.FollowUp WITH (NOLOCK) 
 WHERE dbo.FollowUp.FollowUpDate >= '01-01-2011 00:00:00:000' 
       and dbo.FollowUp.FollowUpDate <= '01-13-2014 23:59:59.000'
       and Status = 'PTP'
GROUP BY [Status], DebtorId)

SELECT t.debtorid FROM t;
```